# docker-compose: assign different values to the same environment variables for each container in a service

Tags: environment-variables, docker-compose

## My problem

I would like to start a few containers of the same service, each with a  different value to the same environment variables, at arbitrary scale.

## Code

Consider the following `docker-compose` service stanza:

```
bidder:
    image: whoever/whatever
    environment:
      - ROLE=...
```

In my system each `bidder` container reads its `ROLE` environment variable at its initialization, and initializes accordingly (mainly, it fetches its `ROLE` configuration from a specific URL and registers as being the role-owner in a service discovery system).

In production, Kubernetes solves this problem by assigning the proper env vars for each container. In dev/testing, I would like to have `docker-compose` assign a different value for the `ROLE` key for each container. I can live with consecutive ids, e.g. `ROLE-1`, `ROLE-2`, but not arbitrary strings like container ids.

## My question

How can I configure `docker-compose` to assign different values to the same environment variable to different instances within the same service?

Comment: Sorry if I don't understand, do you want to use a single docker-compose.yml and run it multiple times only changing environment vars?

Comment: Paste your compose-file

Comment: You can use placeholder in a docker-compose files. Afterwards you can tell docker-compose which env file to use. Same compose file and one env file for each container.

Comment: @whites11 - No, run it once, and have each instance of the `bidder` service initialize with a different value to the same environment var.

Comment: Can you live with a random id? something like `ROLE-12407ff9-aedc-4101-8934-7cb0d876a240` ?